# Data Fetch inside Bootstrap Modal window

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>Model Code</th>
            <th>Size</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Price</th>    
            <th>Specs</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                $f1=$row['model_code'];
                $f2=$row['size'];
                $f3=$row['type'];
                $f4=$row['price'];
                $f5=$row['specs']; 
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $f1 ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $f2 ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $f3 ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $f4 ?></td>
            <td>
                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">SPECS</button>

                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <h2 class="modal-title text-center" id="myModalLabel"><?php echo $f1 ?></h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                           <div class="froala-view">
                                <?php echo $f5 ?>
                           </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
            } //while ends here
        ?>
    </table>
```

I am trying to fetch data from my database.other section is ok. But  which is inside the modal of bootstrap is not able to fetch new data. It only fetching the first data of the table.
What should i do?

Comment: you need to destroy or remove the data when modal closed and before open the modal again `$("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {$(this).data('bs.modal', null);});` OR `$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {$(this).removeData('bs.modal');});`

Comment: side note: ids must be unique through out the document, `<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">`